# Is there a Chinese handwriting recognition feature?

Tags: chinese

I'm new to linux and I was looking for a Chinese handwriting recognition feature but couldn't find it. I was wondering if there is a software or flavor of *buntu that I can download that has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ apt-cache search 'chinese handwriting'
tegaki-zinnia-simplified-chinese - Simplified Chinese handwriting model for Zinnia
tegaki-zinnia-traditional-chinese - Traditional Chinese handwriting model for Zinnia
```

```
$ apt-cache search tegaki
tegaki-zinnia-japanese - Japanese handwriting model for Zinnia
tegaki-zinnia-simplified-chinese - Simplified Chinese handwriting model for Zinnia
tegaki-zinnia-traditional-chinese - Traditional Chinese handwriting model for Zinnia
```

I've not used these, but you could  `sudo apt-get install` them to try.

https://tegaki.github.io/ is the project page with links to documentation and source code.

[image]

Synaptic package manager (synaptic) also has more detailed descriptions of them, if you're interested.

Comment: Possibly that info is a bit obsolete. At least I know that mozc has [stopped to support tegaki](https://bugs.debian.org/985758), and the project is no longer maintained.